# Get back windows 8?

Tags: 12.04, windows, windows-8

So, I just downloaded Ubuntu 12.04, and I "lost" windows 8.I clicked the wrong button... I've tried so many things to get it back, but I have lost my hopes now. Please, I hope someone have knowledge about this, and can help me with this. I really need windows 8 on my PC.

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you clicked and when?

Comment: Also, please add details on what you did to get it back. Have you verified that the partition is gone? If not, can you access the partition? Install and use GParted to see partition information in a graphical way.

Answer (score 1):

When restarting your computer, do you get a screen that gives you a list of choices (like [this image](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/grub.png)), one of which is Ubuntu, and another is Windows? If so, you need to use the up and down arrow keys to highlight "Windows", then hit enter.

If you don't see a screen like the one shown in the link I provided, then you may have installed Ubuntu over your Windows 8 installation. If that is the case, then you need to re-install Windows 8.